# Javascript Problems using Global variables within anonymous functions

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).on({ready : iniciarjquery});
var validaciondeZona = true;            
function iniciarjquery(){               
   $('#AgregarDestinoTuristico').on('keyup', '#Zona2', function(e) {
       alert(validaciondeZona); // undifined
   });
}
```

Please help me, I need to use the validaciondeZona boolean variable as a global variable, but I define the variable outside the function iniciarquery and try to use the variable within the function and global and everything works fine throws me the value assigned outside the function iniciarquery.

But the problem is when I want to use a function within an event happens anonymous when I try to use the variable and the value undifined throws me.
I already tried with: 
window.validaciondeZona, 
also with window ['validaciondeZona'], 
also with root ['validaciondeZona'] 
and also with this.validaciondeZona. 
Please help, how I can I use that global variable inside that anonymous function and modify, please

```
$(document).on({ready : iniciarjquery});
var validaciondeZona = true;            
function iniciarjquery(){
    alert(validaciondeZona); // true                
}
```

I tried it with:

```
$(document).ready(iniciarjquery);
```

And it is exactly the same. I do not know what else can be done.

Comment: It should work without problems. Can you make a demo please?

Comment: When first loaded if it works or global variable, but when it happens the keyup event called that variable already undifined.
As I can do to make the variable is not destroyed?

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsbin.com/ECAgigU/1/edit (I see the value of the variable displayed by the alert as `true`, _not_ undefined.) Have you shown all of your JS?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to work :

```
$(document).on({ready : iniciarjquery});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wbu8B/)

change to

```
$(document).ready(iniciarjquery);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wbu8B/1/)

Comment: Why isn't the original valid? _.on()_ allows that syntax in general, so are you saying it doesn't work for ready events for some reason? Given that the OP seems to be getting the alert from the keyup handler the ready function must be called...

Comment: @nnnnnn - you'd think passing a map should work, and the documentation does say that `on('ready', handler)` should work, but is not recommended (if I remember correctly), but in JSFiddle it's not working at all for me, but with a regular call to `ready()` it works just fine ?

Comment: `ready` isn't a real event, and you can't use general-purpose binding methods with it.

Comment: The reason `on('ready')` doesn't work in JSFiddle is of course because the ready event has already fired, so it's too late to call it again, it's actually explained in the [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), I just had to read them! And that's why you should never use `on('ready')`

Comment: I tried it with: 

    $(document).ready(iniciarjquery);

And it is exactly the same. I do not know what else can be done.

Comment: It does seem to work fine in the fiddle posted above, and I see no reason why it shouldn't ???

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't use `.on()` to add a ready handler, but when I tried it with `.on({...` in jsbin it worked correctly. That is, the alert displayed `true`. http://jsbin.com/ECAgigU/1/edit Your jsfiddle also works if you change the setting on the left to put the JS "No wrap (head)": http://jsfiddle.net/Wbu8B/2/ (Either way I can't reproduce the behaviour the OP had where the alert displayed "undefined".)